# Entity Framework: The provider did not return a providermanifest instance

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

Entity Framework 6.0.1
my App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDataContext" connectionString="Data Source=MyDb;Initial Catalog=mycatalog;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=admin;Password=123;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

And `MyDataContext` class for using EF:

```
public partial class MyDataContext: DbContext
{
   static MyDataContext()
   {
       Database.SetInitializer<MyDataContext>(null);
   }

   public MyDataContext()
       : base("MyDataContext")
   {
   }
}
```

A context is created, but when I tried to get any entity or do anything with Database it throw exception

```
using (var db = new MyDataContext())
{
    var exists = db.Database.Exists();
}
```

exception is

```
System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider did not return a providermanifest instance
StackTrace:
   in System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifest(String manifestToken)
   in System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Utilities.DbConnectionExtensions.GetProviderInfo(DbConnection connection, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest)
   in System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
   in System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
   in System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
   in System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   in System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CreateObjectContextForDdlOps()
   in System.Data.Entity.Database.Exists()
```

with inner exception:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorException: Configuration system failed to initialize
StackTrace:
   в System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.OnConfigRemoved(Object sender, InternalConfigEventArgs e)
   в System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigRoot.RemoveConfigImpl(String configPath, BaseConfigurationRecord configRecord)
   в System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   в System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey)
   в System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
   в System.Xml.Schema.Parser..ctor(SchemaType schemaType, XmlNameTable nameTable, SchemaNames schemaNames, ValidationEventHandler eventHandler)
   в System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema.Read(XmlReader reader, ValidationEventHandler validationEventHandler)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.SomSchemaSetHelper.AddXmlSchemaToSet(XmlSchemaSet schemaSet, XmlSchemaResource schemaResource, HashSet`1 schemasAlreadyAdded)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.SomSchemaSetHelper.ComputeSchemaSet(SchemaDataModelOption dataModel)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Evaluate>b__0()
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.Result.GetValue()
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.Evaluate(TArg arg)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.SomSchemaSetHelper.GetSchemaSet(SchemaDataModelOption dataModel)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.CreateXmlReaderSettings()
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.Parse(XmlReader sourceReader, String sourceLocation)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.SchemaObjectModel.SchemaManager.ParseAndValidate(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths, SchemaDataModelOption dataModel, AttributeValueNotification providerNotification, AttributeValueNotification providerManifestTokenNotification, ProviderManifestNeeded providerManifestNeeded, IList`1& schemaCollection)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.SchemaObjectModel.SchemaManager.ParseAndValidate(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths, SchemaDataModelOption dataModel, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, IList`1& schemaCollection)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.SchemaObjectModel.SchemaManager.LoadProviderManifest(XmlReader xmlReader, String location, Boolean checkForSystemNamespace, Schema& schema)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbXmlEnabledProviderManifest.Load(XmlReader reader)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbXmlEnabledProviderManifest..ctor(XmlReader reader)
   в System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderManifest..ctor(String manifestToken)
   в System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifest(String versionHint)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifest(String manifestToken)

and it with inner exception:

System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorException: Unknown configuration section  userSettings. (C:\\Users\\Tema\\AppData\\Local\\Mgr\\Mgr.vshost.exe_Url_slqi2aqp0duilazpy21vojhl3ssnjluh\\1.0.0.0\\user.config line 3)
StackTrace:
   в System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean ignoreLocal)
   в System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(ConfigurationSchemaErrors schemaErrors)
   в System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.OnConfigRemoved(Object sender, InternalConfigEventArgs e)
```

Maybe anyone encountered this problem? Thank you.

Comment: I just deleted file with UserSettings `C:\\Users\\Tema\\AppData\\Local\\Mgr\\Mgr.vshost.exe_Url_slqi2aqp0duilazpy21vojhl3ssnjluh\\1.0.0.0\\user.config`
and it solved my problem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This exception can be thrown if the login information for the database isn't valid or if the server isn't found or is behind a firewall (basically, your program can't connect to the database). Usually it comes with an inner exception that will tell you more about what happened. Be sure to check for this. There may be other causes for this error, but that's the most likely I think.

Also, are you using SQL or Windows authentication? If you're using SQL authentication, try adding `integrated security=False` to your connection string.

Comment: thanks fo reply, I'm using SQL authentication and tried with `integrated security=False` but I always got this error

Comment: Are you sure your `data source=` is correct in your connection string? `MyDb` sounds like the database name, but this should be the name of the computer and instance of the server (something like `mydbserver\sqlexpress`). Also, try connecting to the database with the same credentials and from the same computer with something like SQL Server Management Studio. If that doesn't work, this probably never will.

Comment: I'm sure, I connected to the db thru Server Explorer and just copied ConnectionString, then just changed servername\dbname\login\password for this question..

Comment: Is there an inner exception? You shouldn't have to change any of those things you just mentioned, weren't they already in the connection string you copied?

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong: It have an inner exception `Configuration system failed to initialize`

Answer (score 71):

In my case I had to hack the .EDMX file and change the ProviderManifestToken="2008"

1. Open your Model.edmx in editor
2. Change the ProviderManifestToken="2012" to ProviderManifestToken="2008"

[image: Model.edmx hack]

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks! How the heck did you figure this out?

Comment: amazing. This worked. :) Thanks so much! I too wish to know how you figured that out!!

Comment: this worked for me too, is there an explanation for this issue?

Comment: This worked for me too. This happened when I downgraded from EF6 to EF5, so I think it must be one of those stray lines of code that doesn't get corrected.

Comment: This happened to me too when I had a project targeting the latest EF when the latest EF was 5. The project continued to work when EF silently upgraded to 6, but then broke when the model was updated from the database. In our case, the ProviderManifestToken was "2012.Azure" and I first tried "2008.Azure" but that didn't work; "2008" did.

Comment: This was a big help.  By the way for OracleManagedDataAccess 19.3, the value is "18.0".

Answer (score 9):

Changed the ProviderManifestToken attribute value from 2012 and 2008 and all worked fine.

Remember to open the .edmx file as a XML file

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the `ProviderManifestToken` set to 2012, check the value for `UseLegacyProvider` and make sure it is set to False.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I'm using Oracle with `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.dll`,
and I use version `12.2.20190115` can solve this problem:  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework/12.2.20190115

Can try to check if the version of dll is correct.