# What is the ProviderManifestToken value for Oracle.ManagedDataAccess 19.3?

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2017, entity-framework-6, edmx

Just installed ODAC for Visual Studio 2017 version 19.3 from here: https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/dotnet-odacmsi-vs2017-downloads.html to replace ODT for Visual Studio 2017 NuGet Package. Then I noticed my Oracle NuGet packages were gone in my VS solution, and I had to re-add them.  But this time I used Oracle.ManagedDataAccess 19.3 (previously had used 12.2.1100), and Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework 19.3 (previously used 12.2.1100).

Now my EDMX gets an error when I try to open it: "Error 168: The provider did not return a ProviderManifest instance. The type initializer for 'OracleInternal.Common.ProviderConfig' threw an exception."

I found an interesting answer by Mitaka here: [Entity Framework: The provider did not return a providermanifest instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19574981/entity-framework-the-provider-did-not-return-a-providermanifest-instance), so I opened my EDMX with XML Text Editor and found my ProviderManifestToken="12.1". So just for grins, I tried "19.3" and "19.1" but neither worked.

Anybody know the magic value? I'm just hoping that is how to solve the error. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. "18.0"

[image: EDMX file]

It actually updated itself after I got a bunch of other kinks worked out including "There is a duplicate 'oracle.manageddataaccess.client' section defined."  Turns out the definition for Oracle.ManagedDataAccess was in my WebAPI web.config and also the machine config.  Had to update THIS specific machine.config:
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config - do a search on "managed" and comment out in 3 places.

Then it let me create a connection in Visual Studio 2017 Server Explorer and open the EDMX.  Finally the EDMX update wizard is no longer aborting on the Data Connection screen.  Back in business.